# Remove last character from array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an array which brings me `19` records in the array like below

[![Array snapshot][1]][1]

My last value is coming as `""`

I want to remove that.

this is where i am declaring and getting the values in an `array`

```
string[] arrS = hidRateA.Value.Split(new char[] { ',' });
```

Kindly let me know how to remove the last value from an array.

Comment: The string.Split method has an interesting overload that allows _StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries_ The empty string occurs only as the last entry of your array?

Comment: If it is last element always then you can just select elements from `0 to array.length-1`

Comment: So..., what is this question about? Removing items from an array? Or splitting strings properly? The author should decide on one.

Comment: Removing items from an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

```
hidRateA.Value.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Also note, `"  "` (White spaces) by definition is *not* empty so it will not be  removed from resulting array.

In case if you've white space you could use below code to filter white spaces.

```
hidRateA.Value.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
            .Select(s => s.Trim());
```

Comment: You have to inform the user what side effects this might have.

Answer (score 3):

You can trim the last comma `,` before splitting your string if only the last item will be empty:

```
string[] arrS = hidRateA.Value.TrimEnd(',').Split(new char[] { ',' });
```

Comment: What if there are multiple commas at the end?

Comment: He mentioned only that the last one is empty. If that is not the case and there will be more items empty then indeed this will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could just "take" if you know that last item will always be empty and you don't need to detect that.

```
var result=arr.Take(arr.Length-1);
```

Comment: Given everything we were told for this question, this sounds like it would be the best option.

Comment: @Danny no, it is not a good option, let alone the best. You should never just remove the last element because it was empty once.

Comment: +1 Because this is an answer to the actual question as it was asked. Of course it doesn't solve the original problem.

Comment: @marsze not even trying to understand the question, but simply dumping a response to the question title is not the way to earn upvotes. _"if you know that last item will always be empty and you don't need to detect that"_ is a flawed assumption that _will_ break the program sooner or later.

Comment: @CodeCaster If I google "Remove last item from array" and find a question on Stackoverflow with that title, I expect to find an answer that tells me exactly how to do that, and not one that solves some other person's program's design issues.

Comment: @marsze then fix the title. It does not cover the question.

Answer (score 0):

This code does pretty much exactly what you're asking for in the question:

```
void Main()
{
    string firstTest = "1,2,3,"; // ends with a comma
    string secondTest = "a,b,c"; // ends with a character

    string[] firstArray = CreateArray(firstTest);
    PrintArray(firstArray);

    Console.WriteLine();

    string[] secondArray = CreateArray(secondTest);
    PrintArray(secondArray);
}

string[] CreateArray(string str)
{
    string[] array = str.Split(',');
    return array.Where((s, i) =>  // return only those cells in the array where
        i < array.Length - 1 ||   // it's not the last character, or
        s != string.Empty)        // it's not empty
        .ToArray();               // in array form
}

void PrintArray(string[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("array[{0}] = '{1}'", i, array[i]);
    }
}
```

But you haven't told us much about why you're doing what you're doing. Do you really only want to remove the last item, if it is empty? If you just want to remove any empty items then `str.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` will work better for you.